¿ Cómo hacer un match dentro de dos listas con un criterio?
Buen día , llevo mucho tiempo intentando esto en excel y de plano no puedo.
Verán

Trabajo en una empresa que corta TELA en ROLLOS para persianas según sus medidas.

Pude sacar dependiendo del ancho del rollo y el corte del ancho de la tela para la persiana. Cuantos metros lineales se necesitan del rollo.
EJ. si el rollo mide 2.50 metros de ancho y el ancho de la persiana es de 1 metro x 3 metros de altura. El sobrante sería de un ancho de 1.50 metros. 1.00 + 1.50 = 2.50 metros.
por una la altura del corte o sea 3 metros. Tendria un sobrante que se pudiera reutilizar para otra persiana de 1.50 (ancho) x 3.00 (altura) ocupo 3 metros lineales.
Cubrí la tela de la persiana pero que hay del sobrante?? SE PUEDE REUTILIZAR SI!

EL PROBLEMA : El problema radica en que ESOS sobrantes se pueden reutilizar para otra persiana dentro de la lista de medidas para las persianas. Ejemplo literal de lo que haria manualmente.


Ancho de rollo 2.50
(Si sumamos ambos anchos nos da el ancho del rollo)
Medidas Persianas     Sobrantes por corte     Sobrantes reutilizables
ancho alto           ancho   alto          (Sobrante 1)         (Persiana 2)

1.00 X 3.00         1) 1.50 x 3.00       1.50 x 3.00 empata con 1.40 x 3.00
2) 1.40 X 3.00        2) 1.60 x 3.00
2.40 X 3.00          3) 0.10 x 3.00             Metros lineales necesarios de rollo
9 metros - 3 metros = 6 metros lineales

Es decir el ancho del sobrante siempre debe ser mayor o igual al ancho de la persiana.
Sé que es algo muy complicado. Por lo mismo busco ayuda.

Es una variante del conocido problema de la mochila, que es NP-completo. Es un problema sin solución óptima conocida. Básicamente, la solución la debes buscar por búsqueda exhaustiva. Revisa este link: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_de_la_mochila

Hola Jaime, me quedan ciertas dudas, 1) cuales son los anchos esperables del rollo, 2) cuales son los largos esperables del rollo, 3) cuales son los tamaños posibles de las cortinas, podrías editar tu pregunta y agregarlos?.

Hola Marce Puente , 1) Para la selección del ancho del rollo el excel se basa en el ancho de la medida de las persianas es decir si 3 persianas tienen un ancho mayor a 2 metros pero menor a 2.50 el sistema elige el rollo de 2.50 para esas 3 persianas para optimizar la tela en caso de que haya una cuarta persiana me elegirá un rollo de 2 metros y no de 2.50. De ahi se basa para sacarme el sobrante.   2 ) Los largos del rollo son de 30 metros en general de ahi se sacan las alturas. 3) Los tamaños varian desde 0.50 metros a 5 metros de altura como maximo
